# Making sure I got foreign key syntax right in laravel 5

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

So I have no problem understanding how to make the foreign keys, yet there's a little thing that might be backwards in my head.

So as far as I can read from the [documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/migrations#foreign-key-constraints) when you define a foreign key,

```
$table->foreign('user_id')
      ->references('id')->on('users')
      ->onDelete('cascade');
```

the onDelete here references to this, which would be whatever you create the foreign key between. A thought example would be you have the users table, and a post table. So your post table would contain  (for simplicity).

As I read the foreign key syntax here, when I delete a post, it will cascade delete everything related to it. But that's backwards? Would I want to define a cascade delete rule on the users table, such that if you delete a user THEN you delete everything related to this user.

Then again, it would be stupid to have a rule that says if you delete 1 of many posts, then delete the user. Could someone clarify this for me, and if there infact is a method to define this rule on the parent-relation (the 1 in 1:N), how would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your thinking makes sense, particularly because you are thinking only about two tables.  The `on delete` statement describes what happens to the columns in the `post` table when a referenced user row is deleted.

However, many tables might have foreign key references to `user_id`.  And, each one can be treated in a different way.  One-size-fits-all isn't the way to go.  So, it really does make sense that this information is stored with the foreign key side rather than with the primary key.

Comment: Ok, so just to get this right.

If I have the following tables:
user <id, name>
post <id, user_id, msg>
comment <id, user_id, msg>.

user defines ->hasMany('post') and hasMany('comment'), post and comment defines ->hasOne('user');

Then I add the foreign key, as per the example above. Exactly what happens if I delete 1 post, and what happens if I delete the user it self?

Comment: @Dennis . . . When you delete the user, the corresponding posts also get deleted.